# Использование super в методах класса

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Пробую более детально понять как работает класс super, вроде бы частично понял, но вдруг напал на один из примеров, который завел меня в тупик. Вот собственно сам пример:

```
class A(object):
    @classmethod
    def say_hello(cls):
        print 'A says hello'

class B(A):
    @classmethod
    def say_hello(cls):
        super(B, cls).say_hello()
        print 'B says hello'

class C(A):
    @classmethod
    def say_hello(cls):
        super(C, cls).say_hello()
        print 'C says hello'

class D(B, C):
    @classmethod
    def say_hello(cls):
        super(D, cls).say_hello()
        print 'D says hello'

D.say_hello()
```

результат:

```
A says hello
C says hello
B says hello
D says hello
```

Понимаю, что конструкция  super(D, cls).say_hello() ведет нас к методу класса B, но что то запутался почему ведет потом к классу С, в классе B у нас получается  super((class 'B'), (D object)) и вот это ведет нас к С. Кто то может мне объяснить данное поведение?

Comment: клон http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607186/how-does-pythons-super-do-the-right-thing

Comment: Спасибо vadim vaduxa, очень помогло разобраться, добавил print(cls.__mro__) и все сразу поянял, так как мы находимся в одном mro от туда и результат

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы разобраться, почитайте, как в питоне реализовано множественное наследование и разберите понятия "ромбовидное наследование" и "C3-линеаризация".

Лучше всего начать с этой статьи:
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Прочитайте общую часть, а потом в разделе "Решение" только пункт про питон.

Comment: Думаю этот ответ можно посчитать частично верным и он мне помог разобраться действительно, но повторюсь частично. Думаю для полной верности надо было упомянуть конечно же про print(cls.__mro__) в каждом методе всех четырех классов, откуда следует, что мы находимся в одной последовательности: ((class '__main__.D', class '__main__.B', class '__main__.C', class '__main__.A', class 'object')) наследования и super(B, cls) , берет следующий класс следующий за B, а это С. Тем неменее огромное спасибо. зачту за ответ!!!

Answer (score 2):

`D` наследует оба класса - `B` и `C`. Из класса `B` перехода на `C` не будет, только на `А`. И с класса `С` - только на `А`. Потом чтобы сохранить иерархию первое `А` поглощается вторым.